# PHP: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php

I am getting this error at:

```
$item->name = $file_item[0];
  $item->type = $file_item[1];
  $item->make = $file_item[2];
  $item->model = $file_item[3];
  $item->brand = $file_item[4];
  $item->description = $file_item[5];
```

The full code is:

```
<?php
class Item {
  public $item_number;
  public $name;
  public $type;
  public $make;
  public $model;
  public $brand;
  public $description;
}
$items = array();
$file = fopen("input.csv","r");
$item_number = 0;
while(!feof($file)) {
  $file_item = fgetcsv($file);
  $item = new Item();
  $item->item_number = $item_number;
  $item->name = $file_item[0];
  $item->type = $file_item[1];
  $item->make = $file_item[2];
  $item->model = $file_item[3];
  $item->brand = $file_item[4];
  $item->description = $file_item[5];
  array_push($items, $item);
  $item_number++;
}
fclose($file);
print_r($items);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, **including end of file**. You should while on the fgetcsv too, `while(!feof($file) && ($file_item = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {`

Comment: We do really need the error that's being generated. Check if the array index exists before trying to access it. `if(isset($file_item[0])) { }`

Comment: PHP: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Comment: that is the error